# Jar file won't run through Node.js child_process.exec but works perfectly fine everywhere else

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this jar file that won't execute when I use child_process.exec but executes fine when I double click it and even when I use the same command in terminal. I even confirmed the checksum of the file by downloading it straight from the source and then getting the checksum of both files, they both matched. But when I run it using exec I get an "Invalid or corrupt jar file" error.

Comment: are you execing it as foo.jar or java -jar foo.jar?

Comment: `exec("java -jar foo.jar", {"cwd": path}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
 console.log(stdout);
 console.log(stderr);
 console.log(error);
});`

Comment: Did you try using the full path to java?

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid or corrupt jar file error not a Command not found error